# Problems aligning logo with the navigation menu

Tags: html, css, styles, inline

Trying to align the HPA logo to the nav menu. Looking at the HTML the logo is md-3 and the menu is md-9, but everything I do just makes it supersized above the nav menu.

https://www.hpa-uk.org/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to make it as easy as possible for answerers to answer your question, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also please explain what you have tried so far and what the result was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `css` you have a `padding-top` on your `.navbar-collapse`:

```css
.navbar-collapse#navbar-collapse-1 {
    padding-top: 65px;
}
```

Just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Its to inline but div  having class "collapse navbar-collapse" getting padding from top. Thats why the issue.